# Be coowner of a Play Console Account

Tags: google-play-console

Is it possible to be coowner with my parter for a Google Play Console account. It's very anoying that I have to asks him to change permissions on stuff that I need to work one.
He gave me all the permissions available but this is what I see:

[image]

And this is what he sees:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, can be only one owner, however he can give you role, the role with most permissions is Administrator.